# Change, Hide and Display Columns from a DataTable in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataTable which gets data from a SQL query(I know how I'm doing it is vulnerable to SQL injections but for the sake of this Question i use a normal SQL query just to show it simpler than three tier level). What i want to do is change the columns shown in a datagridview.

Fore example, I want to hide the 'ProdID' Column and I want to change the 'ProdDesc' Column to 'Product Name' and so on.

This is what i have so far but nothing about it works at all:

```
query = "Select * From Product";
Products = db.GetDataTable(query);           
Products.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Product Name";
Products.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Currently in stock";
Products.Columns[3].ColumnName = "Product Price \"R\"";
Products.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Profit Per Product\"R\"";
Products.Columns[5].ColumnName = "Product Type Code";
Products.Columns.Add("Product Type Name");
foreach (DataRow dr2 in Products.Rows)
{
     string query11 = "Select TypeDesc From Product Type Where TypeNo ='" + dr2[6].ToString().Trim() + "'";
     DataTable Names = db.GetDataTable(query11);
     dr2[6] = Names.Rows[0][0];
}
dgvProdInformation.DataSource = Products;
```

This is how the database columns are:
[image: Database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this to change column name,

```
Products.Columns[intColumnIndex].HeaderText = "Something";
```

And hide ID column with this (as TaW told)

```
Products.Columns["ProdID"].Visible = false;
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Along with `Products.Columns["ProdID"].Visible = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Create a DataTable first and define columns as you wish. Then transfer data from sql to your custom table. Example:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();

DataColumn clm0=new DataColumn("ColumnHeader",typeof(string))
.
.

dt.Columns.Add(clm0);
.
.

foreach(DataRow item in Products.Rows)
{
DataRow new_row=dt.NewRow();

new_row["ColumnHeader"]=item["Column"]
dt.Rows.Add(new_row);
}

dgvProdInformation.DataSource=dt;
```

Hope this helps.